# Run program through terminal with custom name

Tags: command-line

I want to run a program, for example `gedit` from terminal.

How can I run `gedit` through terminal by just typing `ge` on terminal?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I don't see any question on how to edit ~/.bashrc here, that is only one of the options.

Comment: type 'ged' + 'Tab' key?

Comment: @Wilf and there is another good option!

Comment: @JacobVlijm The question is not about how to edit `~/.bashrc` as you noticed very well; the main problem is to create a custom name, an [*alias*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alias), for one command.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Aha, I kind of agree. Surely when it comes to the *title* of the original question, the body however is about editing ~/.bashrc (as well as the answers there). Also the way the alias is applied in his case excludes some soulutions that would fit here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an alias for the command. Open your terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Find alias section and add alias:

```
alias ge='gedit'
```

Changes will take affect in the new terminal.

Comment: I was read article regarding my question and found that it was temporarily. Is is possible to make it permanently ?

Comment: With alias it will work for your user permanent. To add this for all users on the system add alias to the */etc/profile*

Comment: Will this method work on any directory folder or just on /usr/bin folder that contain application ??

Answer (score 4):

An option is to create a directory ~/bin, and make a link from there to gedit:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/gedit ~/bin/ge
```

You can do that with any application; to find out where to link to, type:

```
which [applicationname]
```

e.g.

```
$ which gedit
/usr/bin/gedit
```

Comment: N.B. if `$HOME/bin` is not in the users path, it won't work.

Comment: @Wilf That is a bit faint to mention; it is practically impossible that it won't work if the user didn't specifically remove it from $PATH. By default ~/bin is in $PATH